# Disappearing content in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, wordpress

I am experiencing disappearing content using Firefox 38.0.5, live link [here](http://goo.gl/9Xz6GM).Clicking on gold info+ button, a blank slider will open in normal conditions. At closing phase, the left sidebar text, is disappearing getting back only in the end position (slider close). I've searched the `shiftnav.min.css` looking for any missing `-moz-transition` properties but everything seems to be in the right place I also tried `.bar-side > div {position: relative;}` but didn't solve the issue.Tests are made in full screen, the theme is not for mobile screens. Any thoughts?

Comment: perhaps because I was implementing the above code :) thank you for your feed-back.Kind regards,

Comment: Instead of an edit to your question, you should add it as an answer, and accept it.

Comment: I thought it's rude to do that :) ok, thank you for your guidance

Comment: 2 days :) btw, talking about being rude, do you think that is it too much if I kindly ask you to have a short look to my other question [regarding the IE11 misbehaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30902041/transition-misbehaviour-in-ie11)?

Comment: can't help with IE sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution using the `css` hack [targeting Firefox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-hacks-targeting-firefox/).

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() { 
  .bar-side > div {
    top: auto;
    margin-top: 610px;
  }
}
```

Thank you for your interest.